# A valid case for a single-column ID table?

Tags: sql, database-design

As a hobby project, I've taken on the challenge of creating a database for storing the details of monsters from a certain popular monster-collecting RPG whose name rhymes with *Blokémon*.

The logical place to start of course is a table called `Species`, to hold the basic demographic details of each species. The trouble is, 20 years of exceptions and gimmicks has meant there's not actually a single demographic left that matches 1:1 to a species in all cases. Some examples:

- Name: We call it Bulbasaur but Japan calls it Fushigidane (or フシギダネ if you prefer). Other languages have different names.
- Category: (Bulbasaur is a "Seed" Pokémon for eg) This *would* be 1:1 but recently-added species Hoopa has to be awkward and have two. And there's still the language thing anyway.
- Height/Weight/Stats: Most species just have one "forme", but quite a few now have multiple, and each has different stats and appearance. Many of these stats would live at the Forme level of the hierarchy, not the Species level.

The result of all this is all that remains is the **concept** of a species, and *concept* is difficult to store in a database. For example, Pikachu's a little yellow electric woodland mouse thing, and that's all it ever is so it graciously only has one set of demographics (its even called Pikachu in most languages). If every species were like Pikachu, this would be a very simple to design table. Shaymin, on the other hand? Well, its one *species*, but it has two *formes* - Sky Forme and Land Forme - each with different stats. The Sky Forme is a flying white dog. The Land Forme is a little green hedgehog.

Regardless, species is still a useful thing to have. It links formes together, and every species has a name even if that name differs between languages. You can count the number of species, or look at species that appear within a particular game. But the only field that can exist in such a table is an ID. It's the only thing we can consider *fixed* for every single species. I will probably also include a "Label" field for my own developer sanity, but it wouldn't be considered part of the dataset, just a helper for me personally.

Is this an acceptable case for a single-column ID table, or is there a better way to structure this?

Comment: It was a toss-up between posting this here, on Programmers, or on DBA. Please flag for migration if more appropriate elsewhere.

Comment: You should be confident about where you raise a question that it will be well recieved. This comment is a red flag about this question, which may result in penalizing you. Maybe this is ok for SO on the SQL tag, I don't know, but if you put up the question, you *should* know.

Comment: You could have one table for the digimon itself then add a one to many onto a forme table then link the forme onto to many onto a species table. I think that would handle the above case.

Comment: `For example, everyone knows what a Pikachu` Well, I don't. What is a Pikachu ? How many are there ? can/should you distinguish them ? should you number them ? Do they have attributes, such as value or color or potence ? Do they have a location ? Do they have state ? Are they owned by (or: contained in) something ?

Comment: @AaronHall Well, it's a bit of a grey area question. It's about a design, which seems more whiteboard-y to me (I don't have broken code to fix), but a database design tag exists on SO and similar questions have been accepted and answered here before. I thought it was too specific for Programmers - its not "are single column ID tables a bad idea", its " are they a bad idea in _this specific case_" so opted for here ultimately. If there's a place where I can ask where I should ask a question first, I'll be happy to use that first next time before posting.

Comment: The problem is: you don't describe *this specific case* . You *assume* that people know specifics about your (game) domain. And: these people should have some data modelling skills, too.

Comment: @joop Noted, edited the Pikachu assumption for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an acceptable case for a single-column ID table

Yes.

From a relational perspective: A table holds rows of values that are in a certain relation to each other, ie participate in a certain relationship, ie are associated in a certain way, ie satisfy a certain statement template aka predicate. Your predicate of interest is Species(ID) "ID is a species". So make that a table. You will have lots of other predicates like "ID is a species and ...". But as long as none of them has IDs in 1:1 correspondence with those in Species you can't use any of them instead of Species. (You might be able to express Species as, say, a union of projections of them, but that's a separate design issue.)

From an ERM perspective: There are some species. So there is a species entity type. Its table gets a surrogate key. You aren't interested in any attributes. So don't have any.

There's just nothing special about having a single-column table.